# Cannot read property 'getInstanceByContextId' of undefined

Tags: nestjs

app.resolve(token) throws UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getInstanceByContextId' of undefined

#### Current behavior

`bootstrap` function cannot resolve this transient provider:

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  // fails on versions below 8.0.0 !!!
  const logger = await app.resolve<AbstractLoggerService>(LOGGER_TOKEN);

  logger.setContext('bootstrap');

  app.useLogger(logger);

  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

#### Expected behavior

NestJS should resolve Logger provider and launch application without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

Upgrade `nestjs/common` and `nestjs/core` to `8.0.0` or above